# The cursor is moving automatically to the end of the text when typing in between

Tags: angular

when making changes in any word in between like if I have a word "Line Description" and wants to edit/add the word "Item" in between the end product is looking like "Line I Descriptiontem". the cursor just type I in the between and moves to the end of the text and types the remaining character.

```
<div class="form-group has-feedback m-n" style="width: 491px;height: 26px;">
                            <textarea class="form-control alt inputBox1" [readonly]="inventory.disableFlag==true" required isMaxLengthReached="2000" name="inventoryOverrideDescription{{i}}" id="inventoryOverrideDescription" #inventoryOverrideDescription="ngModel" placeholder=""
                                [(ngModel)]="inventory.overrideDescription" [disabled]="inventory.disableFlag==true" (ngModelChange)="onChangeDesc(i);commonUtilService.onValueChange(i,inventory)">
                                </textarea>
                            <button class="btn icon-search-inv" (keyup.Tab)="op.toggle($event)" (keydown.Tab)="op.hide()" (click)="op.toggle($event);trimOverrideDescription(i)"><i class="fa fa-search "></i></button>

                        </div>
```

Comment: @SourabhJaiswal, the problem is that, or in your function  onChangeDesc(i) or in ;commonUtilService.onValueChange(i,inventory) you change the value of inventory.overrideDescription -it's innecesary because you has yet a [(ngModel)]-

Comment: @Eliseo, I will check the things as suggested by you